# Eliminating duplicate values based on one column's value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, window-functions

I have a table that stores web traffic data, and I've noticed that there are duplicate entries for each record, with a different '***uploaded_at***' date. Essentially, I am just trying to remove all duplicates and keep the most recent date value.

Here is what I currently have, with each instance color coded:

[image: 1]

This is what I need my end result to be:

[image: 2]

All this data is stored in one table, and I'm sure window functions are what I need here, but I just can't crack it yet.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. You would be shocked to find how often we guess that a date is a `date` and it turns out to be a `varchar`. DDL avoids that bit of unpleasantry.

Answer (score 1):

What you have described is aggregation:

```
select page_url, full_date, browser, browserlang, city, connection, country,
       max(uploaded_at)
from t
group by age_url, full_date, browser, browserlang, city, connection, country;
```

Window functions would be appropriate if there were other columns you wanted from the most recent row.  But you can get the date using `max()` and that is the only column that does not seem to be a key column.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select * from (
select * , row_number() over (partition by page_url,full_date,browser,browserlang,city,connection,country order by uploaded_at desc) rn
from table
) t
where rn = 1
```